How do I narrow down possible ivy completion candidates?
I have lots of possible completions. I am at lis and the completions start with lisp, list and lisa. How do I make ivy tell me that all possible completions can be accessed by pressing either p, t or a?
Data I need
I figured out how to find the data I need, but did anybody do anything similar? Pressing f7 gives me the list I need, but in such state it is not suitable for general use because the answer can be a nonsense in certain situations. Opening Messages buffer allows me to understand why, but does anybody know what would be appropriate error message in those situations?
(defun ivy-debug-candidates ()
  (interactive)
  (message "ivy text %s" ivy-text)
  (message "ivy regex %s" ivy-regex)
  (message "ivy length %s" ivy--length)
  (message "ivy old candidates %s" ivy--old-cands)
  (message "possible completions %s"
           (cl-remove-duplicates
            (cl-map 'list
                    (lambda (co)
                      (substring co 0 1))
                    (cl-map 'list (lambda (c)
                                    (replace-regexp-in-string ivy--old-re "" c))
                            ivy--old-cands))
            :test (lambda (x y) (or (null y) (equal x y))))))

(global-set-key [f7] 'ivy-debug-candidates)


The code can be added to Emacs config and is usable as is.
(defun ivy-debug-candidates ()
  (interactive)
  (message "ivy text %s" ivy-text)
  (message "ivy regex %s" ivy-regex)
  (message "ivy length %s" ivy--length)
  (message "ivy old candidates %s" ivy--old-cands)
  (message "possible completions %s"
           (cl-remove-duplicates
            (cl-map 'list
                    (lambda (co)
                      (substring co 0 1))
                    (cl-map 'list (lambda (c)
                                    (replace-regexp-in-string ivy--old-re "" c))
                            ivy--old-cands))
            :test (lambda (x y) (or (null y) (equal x y))))))

(global-set-key [f7] 'ivy-debug-candidates) 

Experiment and have fun.
